# How to adjust for vertical scroll-bar alignment effect on Bootstrap Table column width?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am working on a project on React with Typescript & Bootstrap. One of the components contains multiple tables with numerous entries. For limiting the max-size of tables, I have added y-scroll. But these seems to upset my table's columns width and misaligns them.
(I am using Bootstrap 4+)

Here is snapshot of one of the tables which always has < 10 rows, so y-scroll does not come for it as not needed. It renders perfectly:

[image]

But for other tables, where y-scroll does come since number of rows is large, here is what is renders:

[image]
As you can see the misalignment of all columns (pointed out by red circle)

Here is how I have written the tables in ReactJSX:

```
return (
<>
    <h3>Table Heading</h3>
    <table className="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style={{ tableLayout: 'fixed' }}>
        <thead className="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th style={{ width: '10%' }}>Col Head 1</th>
                <th style={{ width: '50%' }}>Col Head 2</th>
                <th style={{ width: '10%' }}>Col Head 3</th>
                <th style={{ width: '12%' }}>Col Head 4</th>
                <th style={{ width: '10%' }}>Col Head 5</th>
                <th style={{ width: '8%' }}>Col Head 6</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className="table-payload">
            {Payload.map((rowEntry: any) => {
                return (
                    <tr key={ticket.number}>
                        <td style={{ width: '10%' }}>{rowEntry.payloadParam}</td>
                        <td style={{ width: '50%', fontSize: 12 }}>{rowEntry.payloadParam}</td>
                        <td style={{ width: '10%' }}>{rowEntry.payloadParam}</td>
                        <td style={{ width: '12%' }}>{rowEntry.payloadParam}</td>
                        <td style={{ width: '10%' }}>{rowEntry.payloadParam}</td>
                        <td style={{ width: '8%' }}><{rowEntry.payloadParam}></td>
                    </tr>
                        )
                    })}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</>
        );
```

Have tried quite a few places to look for answers for the problem and have tried various solutions. Here is what the Bootstrap style sheet file looks like:
(some snippets from Bootstrap file which have style components used in the above code, and which have been modified by me to help solve issue)

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: black; 
  display: block;
  table-layout: fixed;
  }
  .table th,
  .table td {
    padding: 0.875rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(196, 200, 202, 0.7); }
  .table thead th {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(196, 200, 202, 0.7); }
  .table tbody + tbody {
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(196, 200, 202, 0.7); }

/* CUSTOM STYLE */
.table-payload{
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: block;
}
.table-payload td{
  /* word-wrap: break-word; */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

What else can be done to make sure that all columns and widths remain intact as with the column headers? This should be irrespective of whether individual data inside each  is too big for the table cell. I am fine with the extra data being cropped away.
Any help will be appreciated!
Please excuse poor redaction in images, as I am posting from my org.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, have you found any solution?

Comment: Not yet........